# How to generate the content of an observable based on the content coming from another observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

We have a function returning an `Observable<bool>` to indicate the success or failure of an operation.

```
public operation(parameter: Parameter): Observable<boolean> {
    ... generate dataToSend with parameter values and other information  ...
    this._httpClient.post<AType>(this._url, dataToSend).subscribe(data => { this.processResult(data); });
}
```

The function `processResult` returns a `boolean` but I don't know how to put the returned value inside the `Observable<boolean>` that I want to return from `operation()`

I guess I will have to create a new `Observable` to return it but I don't get how to execute the observer.next with the data coming from `this.processResult(data)`. Something like this:

```
public operation(parameter: Parameter): Observable<boolean> {
    ... generate dataToSend with parameter values and other information  ...
    this._httpClient.post<AType>(this._url, dataToSend).subscribe(data => { this.processResult(data); });
    return Observable.create(observer => observer.next('**the value coming from this.processResult(data)**'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing the subscribe in here use map... Map will keep your result as an observable.

```
return this._httpClient.post<AType>(this._url, dataToSend)
   .map(data => { return this.processResult(data) })
```

be sure to put 'return' before your http post is made

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to subscribe inside `operation(...)` you can return a Subject and subscribe itself to the inner Observable:

```
public operation(parameter: Parameter): Observable<boolean> {
  const subject = new Subject<boolean>();

  this._httpClient.post<AType>(this._url, dataToSend)
    .do(data => this.processResult(data))
    .mapTo(true)
    .subscribe(subject);

  return subject;
}
```

This way the `subject` will properly pass along all `next`, `error` and `complete` notifications.

Notice that I'm returning `subject` but the return type is `Observable<boolean>`. This is correct because `Subject` class inherits from `Observable`. This also prevents me from misusing the returned `subject` because TypeScript's typing guards won't allow me to do that (for example I can't call `next()` on the returned Observable).

Comment: Aha, and how would I push values into the subject object when I receive the response from the httpClient?

Comment: You don't have to do this yourself. Subject is also an observer so it calls appropriate notifications automatically when you subscribe it to an Observble. Also have a look at this which shows a similar usecase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065834/angular-http-call-subscribed-to-a-subject-closing-the-subject/49066659#49066659

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm sorry but I still need some help to get it, where would you add the this.processResult(data) call in there?

Comment: You can add `do()` if you don't want to modify the value, see my update.